# Bulk update array of matching sub document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running on Mongodb 3.6. Below is the structure of my document, which stores monthly rate information for list of products:

```
{
  "_id": 12345,
  "_class": "com.example.ProductRates",
  "rates": [
    {
      "productId": NumberInt(1234),
      "rate": 100.0,
      "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
      "month": NumberInt(201801)
    },
    {
      "productId": NumberInt(1234),
      "rate": 200.0,
      "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
      "month": NumberInt(201802)
    },
    {
      "productId": NumberInt(1234),
      "rate": 400.0,
      "rateCardId": NumberInt(2),
      "month": NumberInt(201803)
    },
    {
      "productId": NumberInt(1235),
      "rate": 500.0,
      "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
      "month": NumberInt(201801)
    },
    {
      "productId": NumberInt(1235),
      "rate": 234,
      "rateCardId": NumberInt(2),
      "month": NumberInt(201803)
    }
  ]
}
```

Any changes to the ratecard associated, will propagate updates to multiple sub documents in the 'rates' array.

Below are the changes that needs to be applied on the above document

```
{
    "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
    "rate" : 400.0, 
    "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
    "month" : NumberInt(201801)
}, 
{
    "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
    "rate" : 500.0, 
    "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
    "month" : NumberInt(201802)
}, 
{
    "productId" : NumberInt(1235), 
    "rate" : 700.0, 
    "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
    "month" : NumberInt(201802)
}
```

Is there a way to update the subdocuments under the array 'rates', incrementally without loading the entire document into the memory, inorder to merge the changes? Lets say my identifiers for the sub documents are combination of `rates.[].productId`, `rates.[].month` and `rates.[].rateCardId`.

I am able to update multiple documents at once using `$[<identifier>]` in 3.6, but with same value.

```
db.avail.rates_copy.update(
  { "_id" : 12345 },
  { $set: { "rates.$[item].rate": 0  } },
  { multi: true, 
   arrayFilters: [ { "item.rateCardId": {$in: [ 1, 2]} } ]
  }
)
```

Whereas in my case, values will change between the documents based on the above mentioned identifier combinations, which comes from a different system.

Is there a way to say that, update all the sub-documents that matches with( productId, month and rateCardId) from the changeset, with new values.

Comment: Good question, and clearly you have done some research though you did not find the answer. So really **Great!** first question here. The one little piece of advice is to make sure in future you don't "obfuscate" values of things like `ObjectId`. If it's needed for the scope of your question, either show us the real value or replace it with something else appropriately "valid". `ObjectId("12345")` is not valid, where as plain `12345` is perfectly valid. Not that there is any security risk in sharing an `ObjectId` value anyway.

Comment: As another small thing. Don't tag with languages not appropriate to the question. If you tag with Java or Spring, then the **"whole"** question really needs to be constructed in Java code. Really this question comes down to the "BSON Syntax" for the construction of statements, and as such sticking to the JavaScript syntax of the shell which you actually included is basically sufficient. But otherwise, great first question.

Comment: Thank you. will make sure of these things in further posts.

Comment: Your question was my answer 8-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the shortest answer, it's both "yes" and "no".

There is indeed a way to match individual array elements and update them with separate values in a single statement, since you can in fact provide "multiple" `arrayFilters` conditions and use those identifiers in your update statement.

The problem with your particular sample here is that one of the entries in your "change set" ( the last one ) does not actually match any array member that is currently present. The "presumed" action here would be to [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) that new un-matched member into the array where it was not found. However that particular action *cannot* be done in a *"single operation"*, but you can use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to issue "multiple" statements to cover that case.

### Matching Different Array Conditions

Explaining that in points, consider the first two items in your "change set". You can apply a *"single"* update statement with multiple `arrayFilters` like this:

```
db.avail_rates_copy.updateOne(
  { "_id": 12345 },
  { 
    "$set": {
      "rates.$[one]": {
        "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
        "rate" : 400.0, 
        "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
        "month" : NumberInt(201801)
      },
      "rates.$[two]": {
        "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
        "rate" : 500.0, 
        "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
        "month" : NumberInt(201802)
      } 
    }
  },
  { 
    "arrayFilters": [
      {
        "one.productId": NumberInt(1234),
        "one.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
        "one.month": NumberInt(201801)
      },
      {
        "two.productId": NumberInt(1234),
        "two.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
        "two.month": NumberInt(201802)
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

If you ran that you would see the modified document becomes:

```
{
        "_id" : 12345,
        "_class" : "com.example.ProductRates",
        "rates" : [
                {                             // Matched and changed this by one
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 400,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201801
                },
                {                            // And this as two
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 500,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201802
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 400,
                        "rateCardId" : 2,
                        "month" : 201803
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1235,
                        "rate" : 500,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201801
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1235,
                        "rate" : 234,
                        "rateCardId" : 2,
                        "month" : 201803
                }
        ]
}
```

Note here that you specify each "identfier" within the list of `arrayFilters` with multiple conditions to match the element like so:

```
  {
    "one.productId": NumberInt(1234),
    "one.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
    "one.month": NumberInt(201801)
  },
```

So each "condition" effectively maps as:

```
  <identifier>.<property>
```

So it knows to be looking at the `"rates"` array by the statement in the update block by the [`$[<indentifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) :

```
 "rates.$[one]"
```

And looks at each element of `"rates"` to match the conditions. So the `"one"` identifier would match the conditions prefixed with `"one"` and likewise for the other set of conditions prefixed with `"two"`, therefore the actual update statement applies only to those which matches the conditions assigned to the identifier.

If you just wanted the `"rates"` property as opposed to the whole object, then you just notate as:

```
{ "$set": { "rates.$[one].rate": 400, "rates.$[two].rate": 500 } }
```

### Adding Un-matched Objects

So the first part is relatively simple to comprehend, but as stated doing a [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) for the "element which is not there" is a different matter, since we basically need a query condition on the "document" level in order to determine that an array element is "missing".

What this essentially means is that you need to issue an update with the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) looking for each array element to see if it exists or not. When it is not present, then the document is a match and the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) is performed.

This is where [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) comes into play, and you use it by adding an additional update to our first operation above for every element in the "change set":

```
db.avail_rates_copy.bulkWrite(
  [
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": 12345 },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "rates.$[one]": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
            "rate" : 400.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201801)
          },
          "rates.$[two]": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
            "rate" : 500.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201802)
          },
          "rates.$[three]": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1235), 
            "rate" : 700.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201802)
          }
        }
      },
      "arrayFilters": [
        {
          "one.productId": NumberInt(1234),
          "one.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
          "one.month": NumberInt(201801)
        },
        {
          "two.productId": NumberInt(1234),
          "two.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
          "two.month": NumberInt(201802)
        },
        {
          "three.productId": NumberInt(1235),
          "three.rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
          "three.month": NumberInt(201802)
        }
      ]    
    }},
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
              "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
              "month" : NumberInt(201801)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
            "rate" : 400.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201801)
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
              "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
              "month" : NumberInt(201802)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1234), 
            "rate" : 500.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201802)
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId" : NumberInt(1235),
              "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
              "month" : NumberInt(201802)
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId" : NumberInt(1235),
            "rate" : 700.0, 
            "rateCardId": NumberInt(1),
            "month" : NumberInt(201802)
          }
        }
      }
    }}
  ],
  { "ordered": true }
)
```

Note the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) withing the query filter, as this is a requirement to match an array element by "multiple conditions". We didn't need that on the `arrayFilters` entries because they **only** look at each array item they are applied to already, but as a "query" the conditions require [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as simple "dot notation" would return incorrect matches.

Also see the [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator is used here to "negate" the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), as our true conditions are to only match a document which *"has not matching array element"* to the provided conditions, and that is what justifies selection for appending a new element.

And that single statement issued to the server essentially attempts **four** update operations as one for attempting to update matched array elements, and another for each of the **three** "change sets" attempting to `$push` where the document was found to not match the conditions for the array element in the "change set".

The result is therefore as expected:

```
{
        "_id" : 12345,
        "_class" : "com.example.ProductRates",
        "rates" : [
                {                               // matched and updated
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 400,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201801
                },
                {                               // matched and updated
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 500,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201802
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1234,
                        "rate" : 400,
                        "rateCardId" : 2,
                        "month" : 201803
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1235,
                        "rate" : 500,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201801
                },
                {
                        "productId" : 1235,
                        "rate" : 234,
                        "rateCardId" : 2,
                        "month" : 201803
                },
                {                              // This was appended
                        "productId" : 1235,
                        "rate" : 700,
                        "rateCardId" : 1,
                        "month" : 201802
                }
        ]
}
```

Depending on how many elements where actually un-matched the `bulkWrite()` response will report on how many of those statement actually matched and affected a document. In this case it's `2` matched and modified, since the "first" update operation matches existing array entries, and the "last" change update matches that the document does not contain the array entry and performs the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to modify.

### Conclusion

So there you have the combined approach, where:

- The first part of "updating" in your question is very easy and can be done in a **single statement**, as is demonstrated in the first section.
- The second part where there is an array element which *"does not presently exist"* within the current document array, this actually requires you use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) in order to issue "multiple" operations in a single request.

Therefore *update*, is "YES" to a single operation. But *adding difference* means multiple operations. But you can combine the two approaches just as is demonstrated here.

---

There are many "fancy" ways in which you can construct these statements based on the "change set" array contents with code, so you don't need to "hardcode" each member.

As a basic case for JavaScript and compatible with the current release of the mongo shell ( which somewhat annoyingly does not support object spread operators ):

```
db.getCollection('avail_rates_copy').drop();
db.getCollection('avail_rates_copy').insert(
  {
    "_id" : 12345,
    "_class" : "com.example.ProductRates",
    "rates" : [
      {
        "productId" : 1234,
        "rate" : 100,
        "rateCardId" : 1,
        "month" : 201801
      },
      {
        "productId" : 1234,
        "rate" : 200,
        "rateCardId" : 1,
        "month" : 201802
      },
      {
        "productId" : 1234,
        "rate" : 400,
        "rateCardId" : 2,
        "month" : 201803
      },
      {
        "productId" : 1235,
        "rate" : 500,
        "rateCardId" : 1,
        "month" : 201801
      },
      {
        "productId" : 1235,
        "rate" : 234,
        "rateCardId" : 2,
        "month" : 201803
      }
    ]
  }
);

var changeSet = [
  {
      "productId" : 1234, 
      "rate" : 400.0, 
      "rateCardId": 1,
      "month" : 201801
  }, 
  {
      "productId" : 1234, 
      "rate" : 500.0, 
      "rateCardId": 1,
      "month" : 201802
  }, 
  {

      "productId" : 1235, 
      "rate" : 700.0, 
      "rateCardId": 1,
      "month" : 201802
  }
];

var arrayFilters = changeSet.map((obj,i) => 
  Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k != 'rate' )
    .reduce((o,k) => Object.assign(o, { [`u${i}.${k}`]: obj[k] }) ,{})
);

var $set = changeSet.reduce((o,r,i) =>
  Object.assign(o, { [`rates.$[u${i}].rate`]: r.rate }), {});

var updates = [
  { "updateOne": {
    "filter": { "_id": 12345 },
    "update": { $set },
    arrayFilters
  }},
  ...changeSet.map(obj => (
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": Object.keys(obj).filter(k => k != 'rate')
              .reduce((o,k) => Object.assign(o, { [k]: obj[k] }),{})
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": obj
        }
      }
    }}
  ))
];

db.getCollection('avail_rates_copy').bulkWrite(updates,{ ordered: true });
```

This will dynamically construct a list of "Bulk" update operations which would look like:

```
[
  {
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345
      },
      "update": {
        "$set": {
          "rates.$[u0].rate": 400,
          "rates.$[u1].rate": 500,
          "rates.$[u2].rate": 700
        }
      },
      "arrayFilters": [
        {
          "u0.productId": 1234,
          "u0.rateCardId": 1,
          "u0.month": 201801
        },
        {
          "u1.productId": 1234,
          "u1.rateCardId": 1,
          "u1.month": 201802
        },
        {
          "u2.productId": 1235,
          "u2.rateCardId": 1,
          "u2.month": 201802
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId": 1234,
              "rateCardId": 1,
              "month": 201801
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId": 1234,
            "rate": 400,
            "rateCardId": 1,
            "month": 201801
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId": 1234,
              "rateCardId": 1,
              "month": 201802
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId": 1234,
            "rate": 500,
            "rateCardId": 1,
            "month": 201802
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "updateOne": {
      "filter": {
        "_id": 12345,
        "rates": {
          "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
              "productId": 1235,
              "rateCardId": 1,
              "month": 201802
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "update": {
        "$push": {
          "rates": {
            "productId": 1235,
            "rate": 700,
            "rateCardId": 1,
            "month": 201802
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Just like was described in the "long form" of the general answer, but of course simply uses the input "array" content in order to construct all of those statements.

You can do such dynamic object construction in any language, and all MongoDB drivers accept input of some type of structure you are allowed to "manipulate" which is then transformed to BSON before it's actually sent to the server for execution.

> **NOTE** : The `<identifier>` for `arrayFilters` **must** consist of alpha-numeric characters and **must** begin with an alphabetical character. Hence whilst constructing the dynamic statement we prefix with `"a"` and then the current array index for each item being processed.

Comment: Thanks you, that was very detailed explanation that solved my use case.